# Rails Contacts App contact delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, contacts

I am trying to simply create a button that will delete a contact from a list of contacts.

At the moment I have the following setup:

Contacts Controller

```
def destroy
 @user.contacts.delete(params[:contact])
 @contact.delete
end
```

View

```
<tbody>
<% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
    <tr>    
        <td><%= contact.name %></td>
        <td><%= contact.company %></td>
        <td><%= contact.email %></td>
        <td><%= contact.phone %></td>
        <td><%= contact.mobile %></td>
        <td><%= button_to 'Delete', contact, :method => :delete %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Routes

```
controller :contact do
 get "newcontact" => "contact#new"
 get "index" => "contact#index"
 delete "delete" => "contact#destroy"
end
```

I have read online that using button_to is the preferred method but at the moment I am getting the following error:

```
undefined method `contacts' for nil:NilClass
```

It would be great to get any feedback that might help me fix this.

Thanks in advance 
Tom

**For anyone looking for the final answer on this it was**

```
   def destroy
     contact = current_user.contacts.find(params[:id])
     contact.destroy
     redirect_to index_path
   end
```

In my controller and the following in my view

```
<%= button_to 'Delete', contact, :method => :delete %>
```

Thanks
Tom

Comment: In `ContactsController#delete` where is `@user` defined?

Comment: Why not just do `Contact.delete(params[:id])` on your controller?

Comment: @Jordan @user is currently defined in my definition of create `@user = current_user`. @ismaelga I am getting the following error using your method, do you know how I could fix this? `Missing template contact/destroy, application/destroy with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in: * "C:/Sites/contact/app/views"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are goin to use @user you need to set `@user` in your delete method or else it will be nil - hence the error message

The other issue is that the id of the contact is `params[:id]` and not `params[:contact]`

I'd just do

```
contact = current_user.contacts.find(params[:id])
contact.destroy
```

You definitely want to be deleting the contact via the user or else people can delete other users' contacts. This deletes the contact and removes it from the association - you don't need to do anything else

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

`button_to "Delete", { :action => "delete", :id => contact.id}, :method => :delete`

Comment: you may need to specify your controller too.

Comment: hey Heavysixer, thanks for your recommendations however I am getting the routing error `No route matches {:action=>"delete", :id=>11, :controller=>"contact"}` I have updated my question with my current routes for the contacts controller - how would I define the this route correctly? thanks

Comment: hey Tom, what is the name of your controller?

Comment: Hey, my controller is named Contact_Controller (which I know should really be plural) :)

Answer (score 1):

If `@user` is only defined in `create` it's only going to exist for requests that call `create`—and I'm guessing you're not calling `create` right before `destroy`. Each browser request creates a new instance of the controller; instance variables like `@user` don't stick around between requests.

To make it work, you probably just need this:

```
def destroy
  Contact.delete params[:contact]
end
```

(When you delete a contact it will automatically be removed from e.g. `current_user.contacts` assuming your relations are set up in the usual way.)

Comment: Hey Jordan, I have just tried implementing your solution and am getting the following error `The action 'show' could not be found for ContactController` - clearly something isn't right because the URL it is linking to is `http://localhost:3000/contacts/12`. Any idea how to fix this? Cheers Tom

Comment: Ah, after calling `Contact.delete` I think you need to use `redirect_to` to send the user where you want them to go after `destroy`. Otherwise it defaults to `show` (I suppose) for the record you just deleted.

Comment: cool, I have just tried implementing this and now have `Contact.delete params[:contact] redirect_to index_path` in my controller and `<%= link_to "Delete", contact, :method => :delete %>` in my view but am still getting the same `The action 'show' could not be found for ContactController` error. My routes are ` delete "delete" => "contact#destroy"` Is there something wrong in this setup? cheers Tom